# How do I remove a module JavaScript file through a theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I need to remove a JavaScript file added from a module through a theme. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey Ravi, what do you mean by "when we minified the file"? Is this some dynamic condition? Do you know that for example https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg is able to automatically minify all CSS/JS assets? And that you when this is a custom theme simply can add the already minified file instead? Is this a custom theme? Or a contrib/core theme your are talking about? Please update your question for clarification. Please don't clarify in the comments.

Comment: @leymannx, the question itself seems clear to me. Minified or not doesn't really matter for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement [hook_library_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.7.x):

*mytheme.theme:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_info_alter().
 */
function mytheme_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
  if ($extension === 'some_module') {
    unset($libraries['some_module.library']['js']['js/foo.js']);
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to use PHP here, its possible within the themes .info-file, see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/257472/44756